# Static Html file of a react render - server side rendering?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

For future processing I want my server to render my React to static HTML  and publish the HTML files into  directory on my server.

How I do this? I looked at server side rendering such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snapshot but I am not sure exactly if it will create a file I will be able to see - when I looked at the instructions it didn't seem to request a path for the file so I don't think I will be able to see the render file.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to give such a vague and generic answer, but really your question (or lack thereof) is vague also, so ....

In short, there are many ways to convert HTML to Mobi, and this article outlines several of them: https://www.epubor.com/convert-html-to-mobi.html

If you're issue is more "how do I get HTML from JSX", you'll want to look into "server-side React rendering".

Comment: Probably better served as a comment (might get downvotes), the "question" if you can call it that talks about wanting to convert React to HTML so that later `this can be picked up for people to turn it into a mobi file` Doesn't sound like the OP wants to know how to convert to mobi but rather react into html. Just my 2 cents from what I understood in the "question"